# Как получить данные с file.dat? C# консольное приложение

Tags: c#, объекты, консоль, сериализация

Есть объект класса который был сериализован в файл "file.dat".

```
[Serializable]
class Price 
{
    private Product[] priceList;
    private int nElems; 
    private double sum; 

    public Price() 
    {
        priceList = new Product[100]; 
        nElems = 0; 
        sum = 0.0; 
    }}
```

В мейне это выглядит так:

```
Price price = new Price();
BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
        // Сохранить объект в локальном файле.
        using (Stream fStream = new FileStream("file.dat",
           FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            binFormat.Serialize(fStream, price);
        }
```

Вопрос - как при включении программы загрузить данные из этого файла в объект обратно?

Comment: `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize`?

Comment: проще будет спросить правильно ли он сохранен

Comment: ну, если проще, то спрашивайте

Comment: нужно сохранить объект в файл и при запуске считать его. как

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx Что Вам непонятно?

Comment: где Вам поставить плюсик) разобралась, все работает. спасибо

Comment: просто подумайте обо мне с благодарностью :)

Comment: @Igor: А почему не запостить ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был найден [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx).
*Отдельное спасибо для user:176262.*